# What to say in this case?

Tags: prepositions

I am on bus or coach right now and someone call me.I answered:

> I am coming after half an hour, I am in the transportation now.

Please note that I don't want to say bus or coach and I said transportation instead of that, and I expectd that the listener will understand that I am taking one of transportation means.

So, in this case can I say "on transportation" or "in transportation"?

Comment: Nobody says 'in (or on) transportation'. We name the type of transport, e.g. bus, car, train, taxi, etc. (transportation in US English, transport in British English.)

Comment: So I have to specify the means of transport.

Comment: I am coming after half an hour, I am on bus now.

Comment: By the way in other language you can say it.

Comment: on **the bus**, or on **a bus**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a useful idiom "on the way". This doesn't specify any particular type of transport (it could even be used by someone who is walking).

Your use of "I am coming" is not idiomatic and the meaning is incorrect. "I am coming after half an hour" suggests that you will depart thirty minutes later.  You probably mean "I will arrive in half an hour".

So you can better say

> I'll arrive in half an hour. I'm on the way now.

There are hundreds of other ways to express the same general ideas. While it is possible to say "I'm riding in some form of transport" this is weirdly unspecific. Nobody actually talks that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.